# .NET C#: IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication return nothing?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, isolatedstorage

I tried to access to `IsolatedStorage` by using method `IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication`, I saw IsolatedStorageFile.RootDirectory (non-public members) as `"C:\Users\{USER_NAME}\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage\43fdwhta.5sf\pamkspbu.odm\StrongName.4lepksw5iyzrojmfb200kvmstgrwryq2\AppFiles\"` while debugging. But when i'm trying to get all files and folder, using `GetFileNames()` and `GetDirectoryNames()`, I got nothing.

Could anyone tell me where I'm wrong and how to fix this?

I'm using vs2005, .NET 2.0 and Caching block

(Microsoft.Practice.EnterpriseLibrary) is obsoleted.

Comment: What do you mean by `result.Count = 0` ? What is the result here?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: IsolatedStorageFile.CurrentSize = 0. I guess it's cause of my problem.

Comment: you cant access IsolatedStorage. This is the point. The APIs given to you are valid if you create your own folder or to check if the folder exists or not.